# Group Theory: Proof that $r^i \neq r^{-i}$ in $D_{2n}$ for $i > 0$

Tags: group-theory

I'm wondering if the fact that $r^i \neq r^{-i}$ in $D_{2n}$ (Dihedral Groups) for $0< i < n$ can be considered an axiom or if there's a short proof of this fact?

Comment: Do you mean when $i\neq n/2$? In $D_{2\cdot 4}$, $r^2=r^{-2}$.

Comment: Can you please clarify with an example?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean
$D_{2n} = \langle r,s \; | \;
 \text{ord }r = 2n, \text{ ord s } = 2, srs = r^{-1}\rangle$,
in which case your theorem is false.

$\text{ord }r = 2n \implies r^{2n}=e \implies r^n = r^{-n}$

For $0 \lt i \lt n$, we have $r^{i} = r^{-i} \implies r^{2i} = e$, which contradicts $\text{ord }r = 2n$.

Comment: I should've added "for $0 < i < n$" since $r^{kn}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, equals $r^0 = 1$ in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: ord $r$ is usually equal to n for a dihedral group $D_{2n}$.

Comment: I've arrived at this: assume $r^i = r^{-i}$ for $i \neq 0, n$, then $r^i s = sr^i \iff s = r^i s r^i$. But ord $s = 2 \neq$ ord $r^i s r^i = 1$

Comment: I used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Equivalent_definitions) definition.

Comment: There are two different notations for dihedral groups both i widespread use, so anybody using either notation should clarify what they mean. But when people write $D_{2n}$ they virtually always mean the group of order $2n$, and not the group of order $4n$.

Comment: These guys say $|D_n| = 2n$:[WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralGroup.html), [thm 2.2](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral.pdf), [someone at northeastern.edu](http://www.northeastern.edu/suciu/MATH3175/DihedralGroups.pdf), and paper by [Arne Ledet](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~aledet/papers/dihedral.pdf).  So there are two different interpretations for $D_{2n}$ and you didn't bother to mention which one you meant. Thanks a lot.